# NGINX not serving from localhost but is serving from 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, nginx

I've set up a new macbook pro with El Capitan, I used `homebrew` to install everything. Also using `brew services` to start and stop `launchctl`.

I'm not sure what the problem is, I have it working on my iMac and did the same thing on the MBP, the config file is untouched, so I should be getting the default welcome screen on localhost, `server_name` is set to `localhost`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try first, on the MBP shell `ping localhost`.

Comment: → ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes    

--- localhost ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 16 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.052/0.113/0.152/0.035 ms

Comment: I think your browser is chrome. And the localhost is redirect to ipv6. Open browser to find the `Remote Address` is ipv6 or not.

Comment: @ZYWJ, how do I do that? Yes I'm using Chrome, but the same behavior is in Safari and Firefox

Comment: @pixel67 if you browser use ipv6, you can add `listen [::]:80 default;` to your sever section.

Comment: This is the output of `brew info nginx`
http://bit.ly/1MrYFwW

Do I add `listen [::]:80 default;` to my nginx config file?

Comment: Adding `::1    localhost` to your /etc/hosts file will enable IPv6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the fix was adding [::]:8080 to the nginx.conf file
I used `sudo lsof -i TCP -Pn | grep nginx` and saw it 
was listening for `ipv6` like @ZYWJ was hinting at.

So your `nginx.conf` file should look something like this:

`server {

        listen        [::]:8080;
        server_name   localhost;
    }`

I installed with `homebrew`

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem.